# Simple question in NDSolveValue (Want to set maximum in the condition)

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration

Thank you for reading my question.

I'm trying to solve kinetic process using NDSolveValue.

The equations are simply

```
Pa'[t]=ra[t]*Pb[t]-rb[t]*Pb[t],
Pb[t]=rb[t]*Pa[t]-ra[t]*Pb[t], 
Pa[0]=0.5, Pb[0]=0.5
```

However, I want `Pa[t]` and `Pb[t]` to stay within 0 to 1. But I don't know how to introduce this boundary condition to the code. Can you help me with this?

Below is the real code I'm using. `ra`, `rb`, are actually having another parameter in here but they are constant that I put for my convenience.

Thank you for your helps in advance!

```
B[t_]:=91*Cos[0.000075*pi*t];
Ea[B_] := (24.5 + B^2/(4*24.5) - B)*(1 - HeavisideTheta[B-2*24.5])-(24.5 + B^2/(4*24.5) + 24.5)*HeavisideTheta[-B - 2*24.5]
γA[t] := 10*EXP[-Ea[B[t]]];
γB[t] := 10*EXP[-Ea[-B[t]]];

sol := 
 sol = 
   NDSolveValue[{
     Pa'[t] == (γB[t] * Pb[t] - γA[t] * Pa[t]), 
     Pb'[t] == (-γB[t] * Pb[t] + γA[t] * Pa[t]), 
     Pa[0] == 0.5, Pb[0] == 0.5},
    {Pa, Pb}, {t, 3/0.000075}]
```

Comment: Can you give explicit values for your parameters so your code can be executed?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. They are actually having multi-variables but I changed those parts into numbers. Is it possible to make Pa[t] and Pb[t] not exceed over 1 or below 0? Thank you.

Comment: Your code still does not execute correctly, even with the explicit constants. Please fix it so it gives a result, even though it is not yet what you want. Others may be able to build upon it then. If the code does not work, though, you ask us to do double duty, i.e. to fix the code AND to solve your problem. That's rather uninviting.

Comment: If you add your two equations, you'll find that `Pa'[t]+Pb'[t]==0`, so you should automatically have `Pa[t]+Pb[t]==1` for all time based on your initial conditions. Incidentally, I think there's a typo in the first equation (in the text, not in your code).

Answer (score 1):

```
B[t_] := 91*Cos[0.000075*Pi*t];
Ea[B_] := (24.5 + B^2/(4*24.5) - B)*(1 - 
     HeavisideTheta[B - 2*24.5]) - (24.5 + B^2/(4*24.5) + 24.5)*
   HeavisideTheta[-B - 2*24.5]
\[Gamma]A[t_] := 10*Exp[-Ea[B[t]]];
\[Gamma]B[t_] := 10*Exp[-Ea[-B[t]]];
Pa1[t_] := 
 If[0 < Pa[t] < 1, (\[Gamma]B[t]*Pb[t] - \[Gamma]A[t]*Pa[t]), 0]
Pb1[t_] := 
 If[0 < Pb[t] < 1, (-\[Gamma]B[t]*Pb[t] + \[Gamma]A[t]*Pa[t]), 0]


sol = NDSolveValue[{Pa'[t] == Pa1[t], Pb'[t] == Pb1[t], Pa[0] == 0.5, 
    Pb[0] == 0.5}, {Pa[t], Pb[t]}, {t, 0, 3/0.000075}];
{Plot[sol, {t, 0, 1/0.000075}, PlotLegends -> {Pa, Pb}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[sol, {t, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> {Pa, Pb}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: fig1]